# Refreshing data from protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, pull-to-refresh

I have a protocol that looks like this:

```
protocol twitterModelProtocol: class {
    func feedTwitterDatesDownloaded(items: [feedStruct])
}
```

Inside my UITableViewController I have this code, that fetches the data from the protocol:

```
func feedTwitterDatesDownloaded(items: [feedStruct]) {
    allData += items
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

My question is, **how can I call that function, inside this refresh function?**:

```
@objc private func refreshOptions(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    // What to do??? 
    print("REFRESHED YEAH")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    sender.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: you can call it on self like this self.feedTwitterDatesDownloaded(items: arrayOfFeedStruct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `UITableViewController` class conforms to the `twitterModelProtocol` protocol, then all you have to do inside the class is:

```
self.feedTwitterDatesDownloaded(items: )
```

Sending the proper value for the "items" parameter of course. Also, the "self" is optional.

One more thing, you're already calling `tableView.reloadData()` inside `feedTwitterDatesDownloaded`, so there's no need to call it again inside `refreshOptions` after you've called `feedTwitterDatesDownloaded`.